# Java/Flask POST request

Tags: java, android, python, rest, flask

I'm trying to send some data from my android application to my server running some Flask code. I'm using `HTTPUrlConnection` to make a `POST` request to the Flask server. I've been able to create a REST API using Flask but I'm not sure why my Java to Python communication isn't working. I get the following error `"POST /signUp HTTP/1.1" 400 -` from the server which I couldn't get much out of (debugging is turned on in Flask). How should I be passing JSON data to my server and how should my Flask code interpret this?

My Java code is:

```
        URL url = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
        writer = new DataOutputStream(stream);

        Log.d("WARN", getQuery(params)); 
        // The LogCat prints out data like: 
        // ID:test,Email:test@gmail.com,Pwd:test

        writer.writeBytes(getQuery(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        stream.close();

// getQuery function aims to create a JSON string to send to the Flask server.
private String getQuery(List<Pair<String, String>> params)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (Pair<String, String> pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append(",");

        result.append(pair.first);
        result.append(":");
        result.append(pair.second);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

My server-side code is:

```
@app.route("/signUp", methods=['POST'])
def signUp():
  req_json = request.get_json()
  g.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (ID, Email, Pwd) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (req_json['ID'], req_json['Email'], req_json['Pwd']))
  g.conn.commit()
  resp = Response("Updated", status=201, mimetype='application/json')
  return resp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// The LogCat prints out data like: 
// ID:test,Email:test@gmail.com,Pwd:test
```

This is not a JSON string, so on the server-side flask won't be able to deserialize it. You JSON should look something like this:

```
// {"ID":"test","Email":"test@gmail.com","Pwd":"test"}
```

By the way, instead of dealing with low-level string-concatenations while generating JSON string, you may use some higher-level fluent API-s to generate JSON, like jackson or the [org.json API](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to use `Google GSON` to serialise the object and pass it to the Python code.